# React.js: Set a Default value into a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Fellows I have made this Component that creates a simple Button:

```
class AppButton extends Component {

  setOnClick() {
    if(!this.props.onClick && typeof this.props.onClick == 'function') {
      this.props.onClick=function(){ alert("Hello"); }
    }
  }

  setMessage() {
    if(!this.props.message){
        this.props.message="Hello"
    }
  }

  render(){
    this.setOnClick()
    this.setMessage()
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.message}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

And I have an another Component that renders 2 Buttons:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <AppButton onClick={function(){ alert('Test Alert') } } message="My Button" />
          <AppButton />
    );
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: can't define property "message": Object is not extensible

On the line that says:

```
        this.props.message="Hello"
```

in method `setMessage` of the `AppButton` class.

## Edit 1

I generated the react application using `npm` and me `package.json` has the following content

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote - I absolutely love your alert and messages. It really shows that you've been trying hard to get this working the way you want. I know those feels so well.

Comment: I just put them for fun. No sweat at all!

Comment: is that even valid? the two root nodes?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I believe that [defaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) should do what you need:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class AppButton extends Component {
 render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.message}</button>
    )
  }
};

AppButton.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
};

AppButton.defaultProps = {
  message: 'Hello',
  onClick: function(){ alert("Hello"); }
};
```

From the docs:

> The defaultProps will be used to ensure that this.props.name will have a value if it was not specified by the parent component. The propTypes typechecking happens after defaultProps are resolved, so typechecking will also apply to the defaultProps.

**Edit for clarity**: There should be no need for you `setMessage` in this instance.

Comment: Sometimes I assign default values with ES6 destructuring ``{ names=[] }``

Comment: @Pedrammarandi yep, that is also a good approach if you're creating a functional component without the need for life-cycle hooks.

Comment: It is almost the same for the case you don't use a Component, see: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-default-props-in-react

Answer (score 22):

```
return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.message || "Default text"}</button>
);
```

This will check the value of prop and if it is undefined or null, the default message will replace the prop.

Answer (score 3):

for deafault props you can do this

```
 const { 
     message = '', 
     onClick = (e)=>{} 
 } = props;
```

and use these variables without props keyword (you can still use props for not defined props values)

```
<button onClick={onClick}>{message}</button> 
{props.value}
```

But for your error it is just fine to handel error like:

```
{props.message ?? ''}
```

Comment: this works fine, when it is  a string or integer value how does works when the prop is an array with nested objects?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using React v.14 or above? the props object is now frozen and cant be changed. You can use React.cloneElement instead

Comment: I think a complete example for v.14 and above would be more beneficial

Answer (score 0):

You cant set props, you must use state instead.

If you need to change the value, then it should be stored in the state due to props are static.

You should do it in this way:

```
this.setState({message: 'your message'});
```

And in the render method use it as:

```
{this.state.message}
```

As a recomendation, you should also initialize the state with that value in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    message: ''
  }
}
```

The same will happend to `setOnClick`

You will find [here](https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md) a good explanation about this.