# Having different props but in same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called Tooltip

In the component, we pass  **"forceOpen: true"**

```
<Tooltip
allowOverflow:false
aria-label:false
children:ƒ () {}
color:"primary"
disableTooltipPointerEvents:true
forceOpen: true
falsehideOnClick:true
position:"top"
shouldShow:true
spacing:9.5
text:'offline'
>
</Tooltip>
```

But in other place used that component without **"forceOpen: true"**

```
<Tooltip
allowOverflow:false
aria-label:false
children:ƒ () {}
color:"primary"
disableTooltipPointerEvents:true
falsehideOnClick:true
position:"top"
shouldShow:true
spacing:9.5
text:'offline'
>
</Tooltip>
```

I have seen this pattern in a lot of places. That the same component has different props or common props. I don't know what it called. Can anyone explain how this thing actually works

Comment: like almost everything else in Javascript, where a prop isn't explicitly provided it will simply be `undefined` inside the component. It's up to that component to do something sensible in that case (in the case of a boolean prop, most often it will be treated as `false` if not provided).

Comment: I don't know if this solves your case, but you can treat it as an optional parameter (search for ES6 default parameters). Are you using TypeScript or plain JS?

Comment: forceOpen => Defined true by default

Comment: so, If I don't specify those props it will become undefined! in that case is there any way to set default values!?  @RobinZigmond

Comment: You can use what i said about ES6 default parameters with destructuring. Or with default props. Check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) @AsaduzzamanHimel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: Set a Default value into a prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419650/react-js-set-a-default-value-into-a-prop)

Comment: I have got my answer by merging @GabrielLima and RobinZigmond answer both of their opinion helps me to get my thing done. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your source code for the `Tooltip` looks like this:

```
const Tooltip = (props) => {
   const forceOpen = props.forceOpen || 'default';
  return {forceOpen!='default' ? <div>Tip</div> : null}
}
```

you can then set or not the `forceOpen` but in the cases where you don't the effect will be the default one.

I am not sure there is a specific pattern for this other then the common encapsulation and the default values for properties :)